# PayPal Authorization & Capture and retaining a service tax

Tags: paypal, capture

I am working on the paypal integration for rental website. I have completed the integration for the payment. Now I am struck on one point: my concern is, I have completed the payment process using Authorization & Capture, now I have to write code to apply service tax on the payment. The service tax will go to the business owners account and rest payment will get returned to the end user's account. How can I implement this?

Reference URL that I have used::
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/capture-payment/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible designs:

Design #1: You authorize the payment and do not capture it, or do a partial capture for the service tax, holding it in a pending state (pendingreason=authorization) for up to 29 days, and capture any remaining desired amount (just service tax or full pending balance) within 29 days.

Design #2: You capture the full amount at checkout time, and do a partial refund (minus the service tax) within about 180 days, or whatever the refund term is on your PayPal account.

Design #3: You implement Order-Authorization-Capture, also known as AS2, which is even more complex but can give you a longer window than 29 days if PayPal enables this on your account. They must enable it, you don't get it by default.

---

A disadvantage of Design #1 is that authorizations do not hold funds on the customer's funding source for long -- so after some days, they will no longer be reserved, and a future capture on e.g. day 29 may fail.

A disadvantage of Design #2 is that you may incur some fee for doing that partial refund. I am not certain what the fees are for partial refund, but PayPal refunds are not as free as they used to be.

The disadvantages of Design #3 are that it is more complex to implement and you also need the help of someone experienced on the PayPal business support or account administration side to turn on features like a window longer than 29 days, or multiple captures per order.

So, those are some tradeoffs to consider.